# django run code before model field access? (proxy model fields)

Tags: python, django, django-models, field

I'm trying to proxy the access of some models' fields. A simple example of the usage I want.

```
@uppercase_fields(['name'])
class Book(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   # .. more fields ..
```

Given a book instance with name='some_book':
Access to `book.name` should return `'SOME_BOOK'`

I know it looks weird, but I need an access wrapper like this around model fields that will act as if I'd access the model fields normally. So a method is not an option here.

I thought of using `__getattr__` but I read it might mess with django internals. Any better way, preferably simple?

Comment: You should be fine overriding `__getattribute__` as long as you call `super` and only manipulate the values of a specific field. I don't think there's another way.

Comment: Do you need to store them in lower case? Maybe another solution to your problem is to make fields upper before saving them, this way you won't need to do anything special on accessing fields

Answer (score 2):

I think you will have to go with `__getattribute__` (not `__getattr__`, because it is called only if the attribute cannot be found in other ways).
Your implementation should call `super().__getattribute__` to access the value and then either modify it if it is in your decorator list or return as is.

Comment: I've just looked at this package: https://github.com/django-parler/django-parler , which also patches model fields. I looked at the code and couldn't find out how it's done. I didn't find a `__getattribute__` method.

Comment: As documentation states,  "Internally, django-parler stores the translated fields in a separate model, with one row per language.".  So fields access is just property or annotation in this package,  which takes data from another table.  But I don't think you want to store `name` in separate table